# unable to update or upgrade using apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, services

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error,

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 331810 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-jasmin (0.9.27) ...
jasmind.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable jasmind
insserv: warning: script 'S02jasmind' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'jasmind' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (empty) of script `jasmind' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for jasmind
dpkg: error processing package python-jasmin (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-jasmin
```

How do I fix this?

Edit:
adding the output of `apt-cache policy python-jasmin`

```
python-jasmin:
  Installed: 0.9.27
  Candidate: 0.9.27
  Version table:
 *** 0.9.27 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.9.26 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

the file /etc/init.d/jasmind is empty.

Comment: There is no such official package [`python-jasmin` in the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-jasmin). Please add output of `apt-cache policy python-jasmin` to the question.

Comment: Your file /etc/init.d/jasmind lacks a proper LSB header. Fix it, or ask the python-jasmin developer to fix it for you. If you want us to help fix it, then please edit your question to show us the first 15 lines of the file.

Comment: @user535733 the file is empty